# Java 8 Stream/Collectors grouping by with Maps

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two Maps

1. `scoreMap<String,Float>` that has a group name as key and its
   score as value
2. `thresholdMap<Float,String>` that has a threshold
       as key and relevant comment as Value.
3. I need to come up with
       `Map<String,List<String>>` from this. read that as `Map<comment,List
       of groups its applicable to>` or `Map<group, comment>` is fine too.

The logic is simply to take `score` from `scoresMap`, and compare it to `threshold` in `threshold` Map. Depending on where it falls(i.e above High, between High and Medium, or below Medium, pick the associated comment from the `thresholdMap`.

Probably like this:

```
BiFunction<Map<String,Float>, Map<Float,String>, Map<String,String>> or
BiFunction<Map<String,Float>, Map<Float,String>, Map<String,List<String>>>
```

I haven't figured out how to do `groupingBy` using a `Predicate` that checks 3 conditions, so apologies for no other sample `Stream` code! non-stream code would look like this(not using Maps):

```
if(orgScorePct >= HI_THRESHOLD) 
    return "ORG_HI_SCORE_COMMENT";
if(orgScorePct < HI_THRESHOLD && orgScorePct > MED_THRESHOLD) 
    return "ORG_MED_SCORE_COMMENT";
return "ORG_LOW_SCORE_COMMENT";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it will be a lot easier to work with a `TreeMap` for the threshold: since it is a sorted map on the keys, determining the right threshold comment for a given value is simply a matter of getting the [`floorEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry-K-) for that value. The ceiling entry corresponds to the entry having a key just below the one given. Similarly, there is [`ceilingEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingEntry-K-) to retrieve the entry having a key just after the one given.

With that in mind, we can have the following (with sample data):

```
Map<String,Float> scoreMap = new HashMap<>();
TreeMap<Float,String> thresholdMap = new TreeMap<>();

scoreMap.put("name1", 1.0f);
scoreMap.put("name2", 2.0f);
scoreMap.put("name3", 3.0f);
scoreMap.put("name4", 5.0f);

thresholdMap.put(0.5f, "comment0");
thresholdMap.put(1.5f, "comment1");
thresholdMap.put(4.5f, "comment2");

Map<String,List<String>> result =
    scoreMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                e -> thresholdMap.floorEntry(e.getValue()).getValue(),
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())
            ));
```

This results in `{comment2=[name4], comment1=[name3, name2], comment0=[name1]}` which is correct: the threshold of `"comment2"` is 4.5 and only `"name4"` has a score greater than that; the threshold of `"comment1"` is 1.5 and both `"name2"` and `"name3"` have a score between 1.5 and 4.5, etc.

Be careful if there are no floor entry: it could be the case that a score doesn't have a corresponding threshold; for example, in the data above, a score of 0 would cause problems. To handle that case, you need to check whether `floorEntry` returns `null` and handle it accordingly by returning a default value.

Comment: Thanks to @Tunaki's excellent answer, I thought I'd also write the other option I had in mind to get the Map<String,String> for anyone else needing it: `BiFunction<Map<String,Float>,
    TreeMap<Float, String>, 
     Map<String,String>> buildGroupComments2 =  (A, B) -> A.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    e->e.getKey(), e->B.floorEntry(e.getValue()).getValue()));`

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<BeanClass> list1 = new ArrayList<BeanClass>();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    list1.add(new BeanClass(123,abc,99.0,formatter.parse("2018-02-01")));
    list1.add(new BeanClass(456,xyz,99.0,formatter.parse("2014-01-01")));
    list1.add(new BeanClass(789,pqr,95.0,formatter.parse("2014-01-01")));
    list1.add(new BeanClass(1011,def,99.0,formatter.parse("2014-01-01")));
    Map<Object, Optional<Double>> byDate = list1.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> formatter.format(p.getCurrentDate()),
    Collectors.mapping(BeanClass::getAmount, Collectors.maxBy(Double::compare))));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional explanation regarding how it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.